# Delphi 2007 (or 2009) build events tied to build configurations?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

Is it possible to add build events only for a specific build configuration in Delphi 2007 ?

I use 2007 but would be interested in what you can do in 2009 also.

Cheers
Sam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

You can have (resource) compiler settings for each build configuration in Delphi 2009. But this does not apply to the other settings.

You can fake it, but it takes some time:

1. In the prebuild, delete the conf*.dcu files.
2. Define DEBUG for the debug configuration.
3. Add the following to the project file:

Code:

```
uses
  ..
{$IFDEF DEBUG}
  confDebug,
{$ELSE}
  confRelease,
{$ENDIF}
  ..
```

1. Now let the post build step check for the existence of confDebug.dcu or confRelease.dcu to find which build configuration is used.

It is a bit cumbersome, but you can do what you want.

Comment: Short answer: "no". Longer answer: "yes". :-)

Comment: There is a difference between a solution and a hack. But maybe I'm a nitpick ;-).

Comment: Thanks Gamecat.  Not a nice solution, i'm suprised delphi doesn't support different build events based on cofigurations but thanks very much for the information.

Comment: @samhowley, codegear is busy processing the backlog of the borland "lack of attention" period. I have hope that features like this are fixed in future versions. (Their plan was to fix about 100 minor anoyances).

Answer (score 5):

Yes!

As you can have separate defines in each build configuration.
You can check your project defines for conditional build processing.

I use something like that:

```
echo $(DEFINES) | find "RELEASE"> nul
if not errorlevel 1 goto
release

echo $(DEFINES) | find "DEBUG" > nul
if not errorlevel 1 goto debug

goto end

:release
echo Processing RELEASE Build:
...
goto end

:debug
echo Processing DEBUG Build:
..
goto end

:end
```

Comment: This works and is a lot easier than the first solution accepted. Note that it should read "if not errorlevel 1 goto release" on one line, but aside from that it works as advertised.

Comment: Hmm, can't get this to work in XE2: I always get "Command [...] exited with code 1." and none of the blocks get executed. I can see that the `$(DEFINES)` macro gets expanded alright, though...

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if $(Config) == Release do_something
```

[Here](http://codeverge.com/embarcadero.cppbuilder.ide/build-event/1069002) you can find some additional info

Answer (score 0):

When using XE, I narrowed it down to something even simpler, if you're interested:

```
goto $(Config)

:Release
compil32 /cc f:\dev\MyProject\Installer\MyProject.iss"
etc.

:Debug
```

That builds my installer only when I set the Build Configuration to Release.  If you wanted to get fancier, you could call Jenkins and let it take over the pre-release tasks.  In Delphi 10.x, you don't need this trick anymore.